# How to generate multiple reports of same format - Crystal Report in WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

The scenario is:

I have a invoice report.

I have entered details for generating the invoice. But I dont generate the invoice at that moment. I just keep on entering the details.

At the end of the day, I generate all the invoices/Bills by fetching, from database, the invoices pending for a current date. Depending on the no. of rows in dataset, I have to generate multiple invoices.

I'm able to generate a single invoice. But i'm unable to generate multiple invoices.

I kept my generatereport() method in a foreach loop, to generate multiple report. But this also, didn;t solve my problem.

Basically, it's not a cumulative report, so, I cant use Grouping.

So, what should I do, to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use grouping.  By moving your invoice details into the group header, and breaking on each (invoice #?), you'll generate a "new" invoice.  Include a Break on new group, and you're set.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But can you be a but elaborative, as I'm a newbie to crystal reports.

Comment: That's funny, actually.  I'm usually told that I explain too much - I've been working on that (grin).  In the report design, you create a group, on the Invoice #.  In the Group Header, you put items that should print as the header on an invoice (Customer name, address, date of invoice, etc).  Similarly for the footer (i.e., total sale, etc.).  Settings for the group would include "New page after" and such.  I don't use WPF/VS, so I can't comment on the code or settings.  Pass the record set to the report, and let it take care of the formatting/pagination/etc.  You'll off-load a lot of work.

Comment: That's a good explaination. I'll work it out. and let you know the problems, if any.

Comment: I cudn't get the sln work. I tried as u said. But a blank report os generating. There is data in Dataset.